# How to contact Apple Support?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode

I had a Apple developer program account. I was the company owner, and I had a user account. I lost control of it a couple of years back, when Apple got broken into and suffered one of their data breaches. I lost control because of all the password resets, new challenge questions, and tools like Xcode logging in with old credentials.

The company is out of business and I abandoned the account due to all the problems caused by Apple corporate. However, when I log in with my email address, its still attached to the non-existent company under the abandoned account. I'd like to contact Apple support and have my email address separated or disgorged from the company and the abandoned account.

Trying to find a support contact is a labyrinth of rabbit wholes that lead nowhere. I visit the website (both Apple and the Developer), go to Support, try a *Contact Us* link, follow it for a while, and then I realize I've been punk'd because there is no way to contact them following the path I went down. For example, I start at Apple's [How To Contact Us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) traverse through *Manage your Apple ID* and it ends in a dead end.

**Question**: How do I contact Apple support to have the email address separated from the non-existent company and abandoned developer account?

### -----

My apologies for asking this question. One would think this would be a relatively easy endeavor, but its not. I'm fairly certain Apple is actively trying to keep folks from contacting them.

I challenge anyone to start at Apple's [How To Contact Us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/), and traverse through *Manage your Apple ID*, and actually end in a way to *really* contact Apple by email (preferred). The case of Heinekens is on me for the first winner. I will ship it anywhere in the world. You just have to agree that I can use your name so others know I was good to my word.

Comment: People have been asking in vain for Apple's email addresses for at least 15 years.  The only area I know where they have responded is for ebook publishers:  ibooks_applicationsupport@apple.com

Comment: @jww Silly question. I know it's quaint, but have you tried [calling a support phone number](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232) or the [developer support phone number?](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php)

Comment: You're clicking on the wrong link. "Manage" is for self-service. The fourth link in that same list is a contact form for sign-in issues. This would presumably include removing an email address from an account. https://developer.apple.com/contact/appleid.php

Comment: @ tubedogg - thanks. That got my initial contact in, and I now have an email address. If you contact me at noloader, gmail account, I'll get you some money for a case of Heinekens. Do you have a PayPal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I contact Apple support to have the email address
>   separated from the non-existent company and abandoned
>   developer account?

devprograms@apple.com